# Weird behavior of Openstack SDK for java: PATCH calls with incorrect headers

Tags: java, virtual-machine, openstack, openstack-glance, openstacksdk

**Environment**
Java 17 + Spring

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.openstack4j.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>openstack4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Call**

```
String imageId = <id that was used to create VM image metadata through osClientV3.imagesV2().create(image)>;
ImageUpdate imageUpdate = <patch data>;
OSClientV3 osClientV3 = <create client>;
Image image = osClientV3
                .imagesV2()
                .update(imageId, imageUpdate);
```

**Created request**

```
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator : Connection established 10.16.104.31:62444<-><my_os_ip>:9292
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec : Executing request PATCH /v2/images/5b9acfbb-1e19-4127-8bac-fe1eae2ed1ad HTTP/1.1
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec : Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.headers : http-outgoing-57 >> PATCH /v2/images/5b9acfbb-1e19-4127-8bac-fe1eae2ed1ad HTTP/1.1
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.headers : http-outgoing-57 >> Content-Type: application/json
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.headers : http-outgoing-57 >> User-Agent: OpenStack4j / OpenStack Client
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.headers : http-outgoing-57 >> X-Auth-Token: my-auth-token
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.headers : http-outgoing-57 >> X-OpenStack-Nova-API-Version: 2.90
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.headers : http-outgoing-57 >> Content-Length: 246
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.headers : http-outgoing-57 >> Host:  my-correct-os-hostname:9292
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.headers : http-outgoing-57 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2023-03-01 19:44:38,113 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.headers : http-outgoing-57 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Mistake here:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Response log:**

```
2023-03-01 19:44:38,123 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.wire : http-outgoing-57 << "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type[\r][\n]"
2023-03-01 19:44:38,123 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.wire : http-outgoing-57 << "accept-patch: application/openstack-images-v2.0-json-patch, application/openstack-images-v2.1-json-patch[\r][\n]"
2023-03-01 19:44:38,123 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.wire : http-outgoing-57 << "content-length: 104[\r][\n]"
2023-03-01 19:44:38,123 DEBUG [http-nio-8104-exec-9] org.apache.http.wire : http-outgoing-57 << "content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
```

**Expected behavior**
When i call it in Insomnia i use other headers (it works well)

```
> PATCH /v2/images/d55969b2-7e83-474e-84ff-29212e80efa4 HTTP/1.1
> Host:  my-correct-os-hostname:9292
> User-Agent: insomnia/2022.7.5
> X-OpenStack-Nova-API-Version: 2.90
> X-Auth-Token: my-auth-token
> Content-Type: application/openstack-images-v2.1-json-patch
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 207
```

**Proofs**
Official doc: https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/glance-specs/specs/api/v2/http-patch-image-api-v2.html
User case: https://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2015/05/13/openstack-glance-use-multiple-location-for-an-image/

Is documentation correct?
Are there any ways to set custom headers to `osClientV3` ?

I tried to invoke PATCH method for precreated virtual machine image metadata.

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/openstack4j/openstack4j/issues/202